# Invalid Cast when the record is guid

Tags: c#, nhibernate

The base has a type of many-to-many .. ID is of type GUID ... while keeping out this error:

```
{"Unable to cast object type \"NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericSet`1[Hospital1.Domain.BPatient]\" the type \"System.Collections.Generic.ISet`1[Hospital1.Domain.BPatient]\"."}

Message: 
Invalid Cast (check your mapping for property type mismatches); setter of Hospital1.Domain.BDoctor
```

BDoctor.cs

```
 namespace Hospital1.Domain {
 public class BDoctor
 {
     public virtual Guid id { get; set; }
     public virtual string doctor { get; set; }
     public virtual ISet<BPatient> BPatients { get; set; }


     public BDoctor()
     {
         BPatients = new HashSet<BPatient>();
     }

 } }
```

BPatient.cs

```
 namespace Hospital1.Domain {
 public class BPatient
 {
     public virtual Guid id { get; set; }
     public virtual string name { get; set; }
     public virtual int growth { get; set; }
     public virtual int weight { get; set; }
     public virtual ISet<BDoctor> BDoctors { get; set; }


 } }
```

BDoctor.hbm.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <hibernate-mapping
                xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                assembly="Hospital1"
                namespace="Hospital1.Domain">   <class name="BDoctor" table="BDoctor">

  <id name="id" column="id">
   <generator class="guid.comb" />
 </id>


 <property name="doctor" column="doctor"/>
 <set name="BPatients" table="BNote">

   <key column="iddoc" />
   <many-to-many class="BPatient" column="id" />

 </set>   </class> </hibernate-mapping>
```

BPatient.hbm.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <hibernate-mapping
                xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                assembly="Hospital1"
                namespace="Hospital1.Domain">   <class name="BPatient" table="BPatient">


 <id name="id" column="id"><generator class="guid.comb" />
 </id>


 <property name="name" column="name"/>
 <property name="growth" column="growth"/>
 <property name="weight" column="weight"/>



 <set name="BDoctors" table="BNote" inverse="true">
   <key column="idpat" />
   <many-to-many class="BDoctor" column="id" />

 </set>   </class> </hibernate-mapping>
```

XAML.CS

```
         myConfiguration = new Configuration();
         myConfiguration.Configure();
         mySessionFactory = myConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory();
         mySession = mySessionFactory.OpenSession();


         BPatient patient = new BPatient();
         patient.name = "Roman";
         patient.growth = Convert.ToInt32("183");
         patient.weight = Convert.ToInt32("90");
         mySession.Save(patient);

         BDoctor doctori = new BDoctor();
         doctori.doctor = "Andry";
         doctori.BPatients.Add(patient);
         mySession.Save(doctori);
     }
```

App.config

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <configuration>  
 <configSections>
     <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" />  
 </configSections>

   <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
     <session-factory>
       <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
       <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>
       <property name="query.substitutions">hqlFunction=SQLFUNC</property>
       <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
       <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Hospital;Integrated
 Security=True</property>
       <property name="show_sql">true</property>
       <mapping assembly="Hospital1" />
     </session-factory>   </hibernate-configuration>
      <startup> 
         <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
     </startup> </configuration>
```

Comment: Which version of ISet are you using ? NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericSet<T> inherits from Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet<T> and not from System.Collections.Generic.ISet<T>. It may cause your problem.

Comment: I am a beginner and do not know how to check the version of Iset, now I replaced it on the Ilist but in any case the same error. =)

Comment: but I take Fluent Nhibernate of NUGET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The casting issue here is caused by the fact, that there are two `ISet`, and you are referencing the *"wrong"* one.

I mean, in your code, you'd have *(well, I would say)*:

```
using System.Collections.Generic; // where ISet is
...
public class BDoctor
{
     public virtual ISet<BPatient> BPatients { get; set; } // System... ISet
```

While NHibernate works with **`Iesi.Collections.1.0.1`** collections

```
using Iesi.Collections.Generic;  // ISet<>
```

You can get this package via nuget:

```
<package targetFramework="net40" version="1.0.1.0"    id="Iesi.Collections" />
```

EDIT: After we've solved *Iesi*... let's fix next

So, you can use `<set>` and Iesi `ISet<>`, or you can change mapping to `<bag>` and use native c# `IList<>`. But in your collection mapping, you have to set the correct **column**, for the *many-to-many* relation, so instead of

```
<set name="BDoctors" table="BNote" inverse="true">
   <key column="idpat" />
   <many-to-many class="BDoctor" column="id" />
</set> 
..
<set name="BPatients" table="BNote">
   <key column="iddoc" />
   <many-to-many class="BPatient" column="id" />
</set>
```

For `IList<>` we can use bag, and see the difference in the column mapping

```
<bag name="BDoctors" table="BNote" inverse="true">
   <key column="idpat" />
   <many-to-many class="BDoctor" column="iddoc" />
</bag> 
..
<bag name="BPatients" table="BNote">
   <key column="iddoc" />
   <many-to-many class="BPatient" column="idpat" />
</bag>
```

In case, that htere is ID column on the BNote table, even better would be to use [`<idbag>`](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-idbag)

Comment: This version is not downloaded from NUGET not at all.
And if that does not use the ISET and ILIST

Comment: PM> Install-Package Iesi.Collections -Version 1.0.1
Successfully installed 'Iesi.Collections 1.0.1'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Already referencing a newer version of 'Iesi.Collections'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Iesi.Collections -Version 1.0.1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: OK, I see... maybe you do have latest version (newer then 1.0.1). I am using the NHibernate 3.3 with this IESI and it is working. Probably your newer version is ok. Anyhow. Just **reference the Iesi** in your Entity/Poco project. Change the ISet form System to Iesi.. all will work (the version of IESI simply is not an issue). The problem is to use correc ISet. Please, once you change the reference to Iesi.. let me know if it is working (I am sure it will ;)

Comment: Did as you said.=) Now, however, no error is displayed, and the data in the table are not made. =(

Comment: By the way I thought to replace ISET with ILIST but IeSI as understood doesn't accept. there it is necessary to use something another?

Comment: Ok, go with `IList<>`. The main difference, that Iesi `ISet<>` will do a bit more fore you, e.g. not allow more *same* (Equal()) items to be added, while no such restrictions for List. But we do use `IList` and `<bag>` only and it is working well. So, now we've solved the issue with the exception... Can you trace the SQL generated by NHibernate and check if it does select related Patients and Doctors when executed manually?

Comment: I've found some issues in your mapping and extend the answer

Comment: that the LIST that at ISET in any case, the data is not filled in, I threw up a link here in the trace, maybe you'll see something here?

Comment: I would definitely set both ends: `patient.BDoctors.Add(doctori);    doctori.BPatients.Add(patient);` in the code. They will be set for you once objects are reloaded, but not during the creation. And also, if the tables are not filled (based on the picture you've sent) ... do not forget to call session.Flush().

Comment: Hooray! Thank you very much! It worked, I just attributed session.flush (); ... although strangely, I previously used a flush only when editing =)

Comment: Amazing job! Enjoy NHibernate, awesome tool